# Casting a IEnumerable to EntityCollection?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm using MVVM with WAF framework. WAF Framework contains a class called `EntityCollection<T>`:

```
public sealed class EntityCollection<TEntity> : RelatedEnd, ICollection<TEntity>, IEnumerable<TEntity>, IEnumerable, IListSource where TEntity : class
{
    public EntityCollection();
    public int Count { get; }
    public bool IsReadOnly { get; }
    public void Add(TEntity entity);
    public void Attach(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
    public void Clear();
    public bool Contains(TEntity entity);
    public void CopyTo(TEntity[] array, int arrayIndex);
    public ObjectQuery<TEntity> CreateSourceQuery();
    public IEnumerator<TEntity> GetEnumerator();
    public override void Load(MergeOption mergeOption);
    public void OnCollectionDeserialized(StreamingContext context);
    public void OnSerializing(StreamingContext context);
    public bool Remove(TEntity entity);
}
```

But, I need to use LINQ TO XML. Check the function GetExamProduced, I've got a property  Exercises, where is a `EntityCollection<Exercise>` and I need to add all from GetExercises(xml), but I'm having problems because the datatypes.

EDIT:
The situation is, I'd like to insert or add the exercises which returns the function GetExercises into Exercises property from ExamProduced.

My problem is the cast.  Exercises property is `EntityCollection<Exercise>` datatype, and the another is an IEnumerable. How can I do to insert all the items from IEnumerable into the EntityCollection.

```
    public ExamProduced GetExamProduced(XElement xml)
    {
        var examProduced = new ExamProduced
        {
            ExamProducedID = (int)xml.Attribute("ExamID"),
            Date = (DateTime)xml.Attribute("Date"),
            Seed = (int)xml.Attribute("Seed"),
            Exercises = GetExercises(xml)
        };

        return examProduced;
    }

    public EntityCollection<Exercise> GetExercises(XElement xml)
    {
        var objs =
            from objective in xml.Descendants("Objective")
            where (bool)objective.Attribute("Produced")
            let id = (int)objective.Attribute("ID")
            select new Exercise
            {
                ExerciseID = id,
                MakeUp = (bool)objective.Attribute("MakeUp"),
                Quantify = (byte)(int)objective.Attribute("Quantify"),
                Score = (float)objective.Elements().Last().Attribute("Result")
            };

        return (EntityCollection<Exercise>)objs;
    }
```

Comment: What problems exactly? Cast exceptions?

Comment: Are you getting an error? or is the logic incorrect? Explain your situation in more detail. You said you need to add all from GetExercises(xml). What is all??

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `EntityCollection` is part of [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723) not WAF. Secondly, assuming that your class `Exercise` is part of the Entity Data Model, then you can just add the `Excercise`instances to a new EntityCollection instance and return it:

```
public EntityCollection<Exercise> GetExercises(XElement xml)
{
    var objs =
        from objective in xml.Descendants("Objective")
        where (bool)objective.Attribute("Produced")
        let id = (int)objective.Attribute("ID")
        select new Exercise
        {
            ExerciseID = id,
            MakeUp = (bool)objective.Attribute("MakeUp"),
            Quantify = (byte)(int)objective.Attribute("Quantify"),
            Score = (float)objective.Elements().Last().Attribute("Result")
        };

    var entityCollection = new EntityCollection<Exercise>();

    foreach(var exercise in objs) {
        entityCollection.Add(exercise);
    }

    return entityCollection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tink that you need to map between TEntity and XELement. You can use
AutoMapper framework to do so.

http://automapper.codeplex.com/

I know that it's not related to the question, but if you want to cast to int
do not use `(int)objective.Attribute("ID")` ,use  [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx), the same apply
for all casting, if the value will be null , you will get Exception.